# Cannot deal with Firebase asynchronous API-call problem relating to data retrieval despite using completion blocks

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My Firebase real-time database is structured like this:

```
 {
  "friends" : {
    "-LhZw8ryHbE-VIeh1kx6" : {
      "members" : [ "3rTK12GBEQf8WMbLEdAz4Pftkxs1", "guHd7whcqyfFjfkduPoCmryLe0I3" ],
      "title" : "Ansh’s Trials"
    },
    "-LhdBeCVRfDVQBtoAeuf" : {
      "members" : [ "3rTK12GBEQf8WMbLEdAz4Pftkxs1", "guHd7whcqyfFjfkduPoCmryLe0I3" ],
      "title" : "Trial 2"
    },
  },
  "users" : {
    "3rTK12GBEQf8WMbLEdAz4Pftkxs1" : {
      "email" : "anshgodha77@gmail.com",
      "fullname" : "Ansh Godha",
      "provider" : "Firebase"
    },
    "guHd7whcqyfFjfkduPoCmryLe0I3" : {
      "email" : "harvey@davidson.com",
      "fullname" : "Harvey Davidson",
      "provider" : "Firebase"
    }
  }
}
```

Now, in the app, I create user groups, and each group is added under 'friends' in the database, as you can see. I am trying to retrieve all the groups in a table view. In this table view, I set the group title as the "title" value for the corresponding group in the "friends" subtree. Given the group key, setting the title is straightforward. However, it seems like I am having problems with retrieving the NAMES of the people in the group. Note that, to store a group in my model, I store the UIDs of the users in that particular group (refer to JSON tree). Here is how I attempt to do it (refer to the pointers below for additional information on the code):

```
func getUserFullname(forUID uid: String, handler: @escaping (_  username: String) -> ()) {
        print(5)

            self.REF_USERS.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (userSnapshot) in
                print(6)
                guard let userSnapshot = userSnapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else { return }
                print(7)
                for user in userSnapshot {
                    print(8)
                    if user.key == uid {
                        handler(user.childSnapshot(forPath: "fullname").value as! String)
                    }
                }
            }
    }

func getFullnameList(fromUIDArray uidarr: [String], completion: @escaping (_ nameArr: [String]) -> ()){
    var namearr = [String]()

    print(1)

    for uid in uidarr {
        print(2)
        DataService.instance.getUserFullname(forUID: uid) { (returnedFullName) in
            namearr.append(returnedFullName)
        }
        print(3)
    }

    print(4)
    completion(namearr)

}
```

- REF_USERS was defined as `Database.database().reference().child("users")`
- `DataService` is a singleton in which these 2 methods have been defined.
- I know the logic behind my code is correct, because when I print the results, I can see the correct names. It's just that I see the names after all the other parts of the code have finished executing. Essentially, `nameArr` is an empty array even at the end of the second method.

So, how do I make it so that the userFullNames get passed correctly to `nameArr`? I tried referring to all the other SO posts and they all seemed to use the completion handler this way. Thanks!

PS: I am extremely new to Swift and IOS AppDev, so I'm sorry if this is still a very common question! But I tried implementing different things I found online (like DispatchQueues) but couldn't succeed :(. Also, this is one of my first StackOverflow posts, so I'm sorry if it lacks detail. Will post any more information needed!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a different structure. Arrays are inherently challenging in NoSQL databases and there are often better options.

assuming a users node

```
users
   uid_0
      name: "Bill"
   uid_1
      name: "Ted"
```

and a proposed groups structure

```
groups
   group_0
      name: "My Most Excellent Group"
      members:
         uid_0: true
         uid_1: true
```

Then some code to read the groups, print the title, then iterate over each child in the members list, get that members name from the users node and print it. I added some comments so you can follow the code a bit easier.

```
func readGroups() {
    let groupsRef = self.ref.child("groups")
    groupsRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in //read all groups at once
        let allGroupsArray = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] //put each child into an array as a DataSnapshot
        for groupSnap in allGroupsArray { //iterate over the array so we can read the group name and group members
            let groupName = groupSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "title").value as? String ?? "No Group Name"
            print("group: \(groupName) has the following members")
            let members = groupSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "members") //get the members child as a DataSnapshot
            let allMembers = members.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] //put the members into an array
            for memberSnap in allMembers {
                let memberUid = memberSnap.key //get the uid of each member
                let memberRef = self.ref.child("users").child(memberUid) //get a reference to the member
                memberRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { childSnap in //read the member in, print name
                    let name = childSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value as? String ?? "No Name"
                    print("  name: \(name)")
                })
            }
        }
    })
}
```

and the output will be

```
group: My Most Excellent Group has the following members
  name: Bill
  name: Ted
```

Comment: I still cannot populate my array. I converted the DB structure to the way you have shown. Essentially, instead of printing out the names, I try to append them to an array. However, the array gets passed on further down without anything being appended to it. However, the names DO get printed out, only later.

Comment: @AnshGodha The issue you're having is you're trying to return data from an asynchronous call - you can't do that. The data is only valid and ready to be used wthinin the closure. You're question doesn't contain the code showing how or where you're using the array but where my `print("  name: \(name)")` is, append the array and once the array is populated *within the closure* then move on to the next task, like reloading a tableView for example. Maybe if you update the question a bit further I can figure out specifically where your issue is.